# How do I convert a string to a complex number in C?

Tags: c, string, complex-numbers

So, basically, I have to build a simple complex number calculator using C. However, both input and output have to be on string form. Keep in mind complex.h is not allowed, that's why a simple struct for the real and imaginary parts are needed.

For example, the string "-3.2+2.4i" would have to become:

a.real = -3.2;

a.img = 2.4;

And then back to string form after some sort of calculation was completed, which likely is way easier since all you need to do is convert it back using gcvt() and merge them both with strcat().

I have tried using strtok to split them but it was such a headache and it failed to work almost every time. It would be possible if both parts were always positive but the '+' and '-' signs were making everything a mess.

```
struct complex {
  double real, img;

};

int main() {
  struct complex a, b, c;

  //calculator itself would be here
}

struct convertNumber() {

  //conversion would happen here. Can I return both the real and imaginary parts at once with just this one fuction?
}
```

Comment: @AlekDavis that question is for C#, a completely different language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strtod`. It will parse the real part from the string and set a pointer to the first character after the real part. Then you can call `strtod` again with that pointer to parse the imaginary part.

Here is an extremely simple (slightly unsafe) example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    char* startptr = argv[1];
    char* endptr = NULL;
    double real = strtod(startptr, &endptr);
    if (startptr == endptr) {
        return 1;
    }

    startptr = endptr;
    endptr = NULL;
    double imag = strtod(startptr, &endptr);
    if (startptr == endptr) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (*endptr != 'i') {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%f + %fi\n", real, imag);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `"%f %+fi\n"`to avoid output with 2 signs in a row like `"2.4 + -3.2i"`

Answer (score 2):

`sscanf()` affords another approach:

```
// Return `complex` value.
// Store in *endptr location of end of conversion
struct complex convertNumber(const char *source, char **endptr) {
  struct complex destination;
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(source, "%f %f %*1[Ii] %n", &destination.real, &destination.img, &n);
  if (endptr) {
    *endptr = (char*) &source[n];
  }
  return destination;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
char buffer[100];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
  char *endptr;
  struct complex y = convertNumber(buffer, &endptr);
  // If no conversion or junk at the end ...
  if (buffer == endptr || *endptr) {
    printf("Conversion failed '%s'\n", buffer);
  } else {
    printf("Conversion %e %+ei\n", y.real, y.img);
  }
}
```

Comment: Pedantically `"%f %f %*1[Ii]%n"` would be closer to `strtod()`, yet I like to consume trailing white-space too.

Answer (score -2):

You used `struct` in the function the wrong way, it's not a redefinable type.

Define it like this:

```
typedef struct Complex {
  double real, img;
} Complex;
```

then you'll be able to define this function like that:

```
Complex convertNumber(double realpart, double imgpart) {
  Complex newComplex;
  newComplex.real = realpart;
  newComplex.img = imgpart;
  return newComplex;
}
```

There is also a variant with dynamic memory mapping, although it was suggested the above would work as expected.

Comment: There is no need for a `malloc`. Why do people always insist on putting structs on the heap?

Comment: If we define a struct *inside* the function, it would no longer be valid outside of it, so we can't return it safely.

Comment: @Lukasz032 `struct`s are passed and returned by value. If one insists to pass these by pointer, better create another function argument and let the caller to provide a pre-allocated buffer.

Comment: Could have returned a `Complex` with `Complex  convertNumber(double realpart, double imgpart) { return (Complex) { realpart, imgpart }; }`